# Galois group of a quartic which is also a quadratic in $x^2$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

A few weeks ago a professor of mine mentioned that the Galois group of a certain type of quartic polynomial is easy to calculate, and at the time it seemed obvious to me so I didn't ask why. Now i'm realizing that it's not entirely obvious.

Suppose we have an irreducible quartic polynomial, for instance $x^4 + 2x^2 + 2$, which is also a quadratic polynomial in the variable $y = x^2$. This becomes $y^2 + 2y + 2$, which is again irreducible. The splitting field of this polynomial is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-4})$, and the Galois group is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Does this information tell us anything about the Galois group of the original polynomial?

Comment: The discriminant of $y^2+2y+2$ is $-4$, so $\sqrt{-7}$ is not involved.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah, I suppose I made an error in calculating the discriminant.

Comment: The exponents being even means that if $\alpha$ is a root of f, then so is $-\alpha$. Thus roots are of the form $\{\alpha,-\alpha,\phi,-\phi\}$. 

I dont think it gives more information:  Consider $x^4 -3$. Now your substitution gives the following extension(s): First $Q(\sqrt(3)):Q$ and  then $Q(3^{1/4}):Q(\sqrt(3))$. Notice that $Q(3^(1/4)):Q$ is not Galois.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)=g(x^2)$, then the splitting fields satisfy $E_f\supseteq E_g\supseteq\mathbb Q$. Since $E_g/\mathbb Q$ is also Galois, you have that $H=\textrm{Gal}(E_f/E_g)$ is normal in $G_f$ and $G_f/H\cong G_g$.

In the situation you discuss this gives you that $G_f/\mathbb Z_2=\mathbb Z_2$, but that's as far as you can go without taking the specifics of the situation into account. In your example, $G_f=\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2$, but the other possibility $G_f=\mathbb Z_4$ occurs, too.

An example for that is provided by $f(x)=x^4-8x^2+8$. It's easy to check that adjoining the zero $\alpha=2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\sqrt{2}+1}$ produces a splitting field, and if we map $\alpha$ to one of the other two conjugates $\not=\pm\alpha$, then the corresponding automorphism doesn't have order $2$, which proves the claim on the Galois group.

Comment: And as @Ryan notes in a comment, even if $f(x)=g(x^2)$, the degree of $E_f$ over $E_g$ may be 4, not 2.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the splitting field of $x^4+2x^2+2$ over the rationals is ${\bf Q}(i,\sqrt2)$, from which it's easy to work out that the Galois group is Klein-4.

Comment: That's not really the spirit of the question though. This was an artificial example in which it's easy to calculate the Galois group directly, but what I was curious about what a specific approach to finding the Galois group. For example, suppose the polynomial was instead $x^9 + 2x^3 + 2$, in which case it is probably not easy to directly calculate the Galois group. In this case, this polynomial is $y^2 + 2y + 2$, in the change $y = x^3$. So does knowing the Galois group of the polynomial $y^2 + 2y +2$ give any information about the Galois group of the original polynomial?

Comment: Do you mean $x^6+2x^3+2$? or do you mean $y^3+2y+2$? In any event, you have fields ${\bf Q}\subset E\subset K$ where you know the Galois group of $E/{\bf Q}$ and $K$ is a pure cubic extension of $E$ so you know the Galois group of $K/E$. This by itself may not be enough to tell you everything about the group of $K/{\bf Q}$, but it certainly tells you quite a bit.